# Clearing selecteditem of listbox (which is bound to collection of objects) with MVVM

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have a listbox with silverlight 4.  I have the list bound to a list of objects.

1.) The SelectedValue property is bound to a public property of the viewmodel called Current.  How do i clear the selection?  I have tried setting the value of Current to null.  Well, this clears the selection however it also breaks binding in the edit form which has a combobox bound to a property of 'Current'.  Textboxes which are bound to Current.FirstName etc. are working ok however the comboboxes do not function after I set the Current object to null.

2.) how do i load the form without the first item being selected?

Comment: I think this is an obsolete question. The only thing needed was Setting "Current" to null. If the bindings are fine this should work. See http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-4-Integrating-with-the-Model-View-ViewModel-Pattern.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around for this bug in Silverlight:

```
// Bug in SL listbox prevents SelectedIndex = -1 from unselected.
// Workaround is to use DispatcherBeginInvoke to do it async. Found
// work around here:
// http://sharplogic.com/blogs/rdavis/PermaLink,guid,2f5bbfa1-4878-490f-967d-bf00bc04dfde.aspx
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { QuickItemsListBox.SelectedIndex = -1; });
```

More details here:
http://sharplogic.com/blogs/rdavis/PermaLink,guid,2f5bbfa1-4878-490f-967d-bf00bc04dfde.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when it was fixed but VoodooChild's answer works now in Silverlight 5.  Passing this along in case others are looking.

```
yourCB.selectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

`yourCB.SelectedIndex = -1;`

Comment: @cek: hmmm, I apologize - didn't know it was a bug.