# how to remove custome items from observablecollection in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

i binded one observable cllection to one listbox in silverlight.when i click one item in listbox and click delete button ,how to remove that particular item remove from the listbox without linq using mvvm.i passed commandparameter of the button is listbox itemid.

```
 <ListBox   ItemsSource="{Binding School1,Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="SchoolName"  Name="listBox1"  >
<Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding deletecommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.ID,ElementName=listBox1}"   Name="button2" />
```

so what is the code for remove particular item from observable collection

```
public void delete(object parameter)
{
School1.Remove(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the ListBox's [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to a property and use that in your Remove():

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding School1, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="SchoolName"  
          SelectedItem={Binding SelectedSchool}
          Name="listBox1"  
          />


public void delete(object parameter)
{
    if (SelectedSchool != null)
        School1.Remove(SelectedSchool);
}
```

Also note that your question is somewhat of a duplicate: [Clearing selecteditem of listbox (which is bound to collection of objects) with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653388/clearing-selecteditem-of-listbox-which-is-bound-to-collection-of-objects-with)

Comment: hi @slugster  i made one string property for selectedschool and binded.when i write school1.remove(selectedschool) its making error..

Comment: @nixen09 And what is the error? Did you put a breakpoint in the code of the `delete()` function so that you could use the debugger to inspect the values in there?

Comment: i cleard that one. i use selectedindex and using that i delete the value from observablecollection.when i use selected item i got that particular classname.error is , it has some invalid argument.i write the code like this school1.remove(selecteditem).i try to find the error when i use selecteditem but i can't pls solve this..