# Best practice to delete item from collection

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, collections, ienumerable

I've got a class like this

```
Public Class Car
    Public Property Brand As String
    Public Property Model As String
    Public Property Horsepower As Integer
End Class
```

And made a collection of objects from this class like this

```
Dim myCarCollection As List(Of Car) = New List(Of Car) From {
New Car() With {.Brand = "VW", .Model = "Golf", .Horsepower = "100"},
New Car() With {.Brand = "Mercedes", .Model = "C220", .Horsepower = "110"},
New Car() With {.Brand = "Porsche", .Model = "911", .Horsepower = "341"}}
```

Now e.g. I want to delete all cars where the Brand is not VW and which have less horsepower than 300. Which is the "best" way to do it? I saw that the collection has something like `myCarCollection.Where`, can somebody maybe explain how to do this?

Edit: I know how to do it with `for`/`foreach` but I was thinking about a smarter way to do it.

Comment: Do you actually want to delete the items from the collection (thereby reducing the length of the list) or get a subset of cars except the criteria you mentioned?

Comment: I want to delete them from the collection

Comment: Don't put quotes around numbers. If a property is an `Integer` then you shouldn't feed it a `String`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the Cars that doesn't satisfy your conditions using RemoveAll

```
myCarCollection.RemoveAll(Function(x) x.Brand <> "VW" AndAlso
                          x.Horsepower < 300)
```

When you add a Car to the collection do not use the automatic conversion provided by VB compiler thanks to [Option Strict set to Off](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement). In the long run this option has more troubles than benefits.

Comment: Horsepower is already an Integer or am I wrong? But thanks, perfect solution! :)

Comment: Oh yes sorry, confused by the Add in the collection where you used strings.

Comment: But what if I am using a OberservableCollection, there is no RemoveAll. Is there any similar solution?

Comment: My mistake by the Adding!

Comment: Uhm no, you could remove items iterating over a copy of the collection as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472321/remove-multiple-items-from-observablecollection-in-silverlight

Comment: Or you could use the Where extension to get a copy of the items to remove, loop over the items and call remove passing the item

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_RemoveAll_System_Predicate__0__):

```
myCarCollection.RemoveAll(Function(c As Car) c.Brand <> "VW" AndAlso
                                             c.Horsepower < 300)
```